# Any issue with package format 3 in ros kinetic?

Tags: ros, package, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any issues with using package.xml format 3 in ROS kinetic as long as the catkin version is up to date? Is any of the functionality not supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355136/any-issue-with-package-format-3-in-ros-kinetic?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-17**:
I'm not aware of any limitations or problems. Catkin versions are not really linked to ROS releases, so you should not have any problems using version 3 on Kinetic.

Have you run into anything?

**Comment by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on 2020-06-17**:
I haven't had any issues yet, but I'm working on outlining a ROS2 upgrade for my project and it may depend on the new features of format 3 so I wanted to check and make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While there don't seem to be any specific recommendations on which distros support [REP-149](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html), catkin itself got upgraded to a format 3 package.xml in this PR into kinetic-devel in 2019: https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1025

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1